# Can ordered triples, quadruples, be defined in this alternative way?

Tags: set-theory

The ordered pair $(a,b)$ is defined in formal set theory as the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. Then ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ are defined in this way: $((a,b),c)$. However, can we define ordered triples as the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$, and analogously for higher n-tuples. In other words, does such a definition uniquely determine the components of the ordered triple?

Comment: Think about what happens if $a=b=c$.

Comment: What about $(2,3,2)$ versus $(2,3,3)$?